# Store html in database in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, database

Hello I'm trying to store HTML code in the database with Django but facing a problem with escape characters.

here's an object that I'm trying to store but

```
{
   "data": "<div class=\"read\" id=\"search\">Google</div>"
}
```

here's what I'm getting in database.

```
<div class="read" id="search">Google</div>
```

I tried to store with `Model.objects.create()`

this becomes a problem to parse too much HTML in javascript then. JSON object gets confused with the double-quotes. the solution is I want to store data in database with backslashes `\` as well so it can be parsed correctly as a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a triple slash?  Two to create an escaped backslash and then one to escape the doublequote

```
{
   "data": "<div class=\\\"read\\\" id=\\\"search\\\">Google</div>"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's working but I'm still facing a problem for `\n` it totally skips `\n` and in final result `\n` doesn't appear.

Comment: If it's the same situation as in the question,  \\n should do it.  However, \n isn't html so it won't show up on a web page, you would need <br> instead. If you are just wanting to format the json itself you might want to look into the python json module which is another way of handling this type of situation,  but is a little outside the question's scope